# How to resize image without adding noise with python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I have an image and I want to resize and expand this image without spoiling it.

The image:

[image: Image work]

The image size:

- w=41
- h=43

The image size I want it resized to:

- w=2000x
- h=2100

I tried all the known methods:

1. with PIL.Image:

   ```
   from PIL import Image
   path = "image.png"
   w, h = 2000, 2100
   img = Image.open(path)
   img = img.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
   img.save("re_image.png", "PNG")
   ```
2. with cv2:

   ```
   import cv2
   path = "image.png"
   w, h = 2000, 2100
   img = cv2.imread(path)
   img = cv2.resize(img, (w, h), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
   cv2.imwrite("re_image.png", img)
   ```

The result is:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: It depends on what you want the final image to look like. If you want it to keep it's pixelation the `cv2.INTER_NEAREST` is probably your best bet. All methods of interpolating between existing pixels will create some artefact. Especially at the scales you are attempting.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the `ANTIALIAS` filter. Since you want to preserve the sharpness of the edges, simply use the `NEAREST` filter. This filter is the default if no argument is passed to the `resample` parameter of [`Image.resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

```
img = img.resize((w, h))
```

This gives the expected result

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case which is a binary image, I think that you want to keep the edges sharp. Then I would suggest to use the flag cv2.INTER_NEAREST in your openCV implementation. You can check the effect of the different interpolation types, given in the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: If you use Pillow, it looks like NEAREST is not default so you have you use

`img = img.resize((w, h), PIL.Image.NEAREST)`

Answer (score -1):

I created a simple function. Please give me your opinion.

The function is:

```
 import cv2, numpy as np

 def resize(path, sizes = (500, 800)):
         nw, nh = sizes
         g_img = cv2.imread(path)

         gw, gh = g_img.shape[0], g_img.shape[1]
         nw, nh = gw+510, gh+510
         pw, ph = int(nw/gw), int(nh/gh)
         if (pw == 0):pw = 1
         if (ph == 0):ph = 1
         nw, nh = pw*gw, ph*gh

         cvimg = np.zeros((nh,nw,3), np.uint8)

         for gy in range(gh):
             y, h = gy*ph, (gy*ph)+ph
             for gx in range(gw):
                 x, w = gx*pw, (gx*pw)+pw
                 cvimg[y:h, x:w] = g_img[gy:gy+1, gx:gx+1]

         nsize = [nw, nh]
         return cvimg, nsize
```

The result is:

[image: Result]